Complementary function for repeated roots
Let,
$$f(D)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}D^{k}$$
Where $a_k$ is in real numbers. And $D^k$ denotes the $k$-th derivative operator.
One can say that,
$$f(D)y=0$$
Is a $n$ order differential equation with constant coefficients.
Now if I consider the auxiliary equation corresponding to $f(D)$
It will be
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}$$
I compute the roots for $g(x)$, say $m_1,m_2...,m_n$ are distinct and real then it's really simple to show that,
$$\text{CF}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_ke^{m_kx}$$
My question:-
$(1)$ Derive the suppose two of the roots are repeating (say $m_1,m_2$) then how to show that the $\text{CF}$ is,
$$(c_1+c_{2}x)e^{m_1x}+c_{3}e^{m_2x}+....+c_{n}e^{lx}$$
For some $n,l$
